# PDO not catching error when I SELECT a table that doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to try/catch a PDO::query to make sure whether a table exists or not. But Instead of catching the error and returning true or false it is just throwing an uncaught error:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->db = parent::connect();
}

public function table_exists($table){
        try {
            $this->query("SELECT 1 FROM `$table` LIMIT 1");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function query($sql){
        try {
            $this->result = $this->db->query($sql);
            return $this;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I also tried this `$this->db->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` inside the try's but it didn't make any difference. So I get

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'refritec.user' doesn't exist' in
>   ...\DatabaseDriverMysql.php:34 Stack trace:
>   0 ...\DatabaseDriverMysql.php(34): PDO->query('SELECT 1 FROM ...') 1
>   ...\DatabaseDriverMysql.php(25):
>   Core\DatabaseDriver->query('SELECT 1 FROM `...') 2
>   ...\Pen.php(123):
>   Core\DatabaseDriver->table_exists('user') #3 [internal function]:
>   Core\Pen->update() #4 ...\index.php(97):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #5 {main} thrown in
>   ...\DatabaseDriverMysql.php on line 34

Comment: Is the code above in a file that is namespaced?

Comment: Try with `\Exception` instead of `Exception`. Or, since you are using PDO, use `\PDOException`.

Comment: ^^^ that's what I was getting at

Comment: @xjstratedgebx You didn't quite get to the point, so I made it for you.

Comment: you did it @SverriM.Olsen

Comment: No worries, so long as the OP gets the answer, that's what we're here for. I was using the comment to get clarification on the question, to then provide an actual answer, as I understand that to be the process. If we're right though, properly namespacing the Exception should do the trick.

Comment: @VictorFerreira you are getting `true` always right?

Comment: @VictorFerreira how you are using result returned from `table_exists()`?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 Sverri found the answer. I'm using Namespace and I had to use \Exception to refer to the native class.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from that silly typo explained in comments, your approach is essentially wrong.

First, you aren't checking the particular exception. Means there will be false positive in case of *any* error, not only absent table.

Second, your code is prone to SQL injection.

Third, you are writing a code that is raising a deliberate error. That's wrong again. As long as there are means to check the table existence the *regular way*, you have to use it:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SHOW TABLES LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute([$table]);
return $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Fourth, such a function itself arises suspicions for the database design. Ina sanely designed application there is no need to create tables dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

I´m not able to recreate your exact problem but did you try catching the `PDOException` like:

```
try {
    $this->query("SELECT 1 FROM `$table` LIMIT 1");
    return true;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    return false;
}
```

**Edited**

You also have to use `$this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` on your connection. because PDO doesn't throw exceptions by default like seen [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php).

Comment: I didn't, my friend, but it still don't work. my version of PHP didn't allow me to use return inside `die`. without the `return`, only `false`, it gives me the same error

Comment: `PDOException` extends `Exception`. This shouldn't make a difference. Also, answers should *answer* the question, not guess at what it might be. If you need more information, or if you are not sure, then write a comment instead.

Comment: I edited my answer. Try the `setAttribute`, then you should be able to catch the exception.

Answer (score -1):

I use the simple query to see if the table exists, if the value is different from "0" there is a value with that I can show the message I want.

```
    $res = $this->db->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$tbname."perfil'");

    $count = $res->num_rows();
```